# AngularJS image upload preview without directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I'm uploading files via service:

```
var addFile = function(files) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", files[0]);
  $http.post("/files", fd, {
      ***
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      ***
    })
    .error(function(err, status) {
      ***
    });
    ***
};
```

and in controller I have something like:

```
uplService.addFile($scope.files).then(function(url) {
  $scope.news.Photo = url;
});
```

and in HTML view:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" />
```

before that I uploaded file on-the-go, when I select file it goes directly to server, but now I need to display it in my form when I select it, but upload later, all I see in web is using directives, but how could I organize it without using directives?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader for show the file before upload and all in all I prefer using a dedicate module https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular+file+upload

Comment: @Whisher i need with example

Comment: well if you need with example ... start searching based on what you just learned from link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read this [article](http://macaalay.com/2014/09/26/rendering-images-from-byte-arrays-and-converting-images-to-byte-arrays-using-angularjs/), which helped me to solve the problem about uploading the image.

If you want to show your selected file, try this:

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{news.Photo}}" id="photo-id"/>
```

*Explanation*:

Your property for image in Model/ViewModel/Class must be an array of bytes, like

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

The data:image/jpeg;base64 defines the byte array from `news.Photo` so it can be rendered correctly on the clients browser.

The `$scope.news.Photo` in your case is just an scoped variable which contains the drawed image with byte created by the byte equivalent in the $scope.uploadFile  function from article.

I hope it will be also helpful for you.

Comment: {{news.Photo}} - but what to put there? files[0] or what? thank you

Comment: note, image is located in browser, not on server until i click 'save'

Comment: I know that it must be shown before 'save', I updated my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Can you try this in your controller to pass your file object here:

```
$scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
$scope.photoChanged = function(files){
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
    if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
};
```

and on the view

```
<img ng-show="thumbnail.dataUrl != null" ng-src="{{ thumbnail.dataUrl }}" class="thumb">
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/639kbzyd/2/)

Hope this help